# Apache PHP mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to test out the mod_rewrite meaning: 
I have two files: **level1.php** and **warpzone.php**.

In my **.htaccess** I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^warp-zone.php$ level-1.php
```

Yet when I go to warpzone.php, nothing happens :/ (the url doesn't change)

Any suggestions? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: is the rewrite mode enabled in apache, use command a2enmod rewrite   and restart your apache

Comment: I added `apache`to your tittle and tags, `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module, has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: The problem is on the Apache Server configuration. Has it `mod_rewrite` enabled? Are you using `VirtualHost`? Has your host/folder the `allow` directive to let you use this in your `.htaccess` file? Can you manage the server? A lot of questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have dashes in php file names at your .htaccess file, while your files does not have them.

Rewrite conditions - this changes the content to new one, but URL stays as it was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^warpzone\.php$  level1.php  [L]
```

Redirect conditions - this changes both content and URL to new one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^warpzone\.php$  /level1.php  [R]
```

Also you can use Redirect condition instead of mod_rewrite:

```
Redirect 301 /warpzone.php /level1.php
```

In case if it does not work for you, you can use headers() method at the top of your `warpzone.php` file:

```
<?php 
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/level1.php");
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

- check whether warpzone.php or warp-zone.php is the correct filename, you are mixing them in your example.
- check the apache error.log file if mod_rewrite is available, if not then enable it (this can be done either with "LoadModule ..." or it is wrapped by your Linux distribution)
- check the apache error.log if you are allowed to use mod_rewrite, if not consider setting "AllowOverride All" in global config files httpd.conf/apache2.conf
- change your rewrite rule to "RewriteRule ^warp-zone.php$ level-1.php **[L]**" to issue an http redirect; without L flag, is is handled internally in the web sever; see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html for all flags

regards